Not able to understand why the given CSS is not working
This is basically a youtube clone which i am working on. The contents of the sidebar should be in the middle. But i am not able to bring the contents to the middle.



.sidebar {
  background-color: rgb(175, 146, 146);
  width: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: fixed;
  align-items: center;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 72px;
  padding-top: 15px;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.home-img {
  width: 24px;
}

.home {
  width: 100%;
}

.explore-img {
  width: 24px;
}

.explore {
  width: 100%;
}

.subscriptions-img {
  width: 24px;
}

.subscriptions {
  width: 100%;
}

.originals-img {
  width: 24px;
}

.originals {
  width: 100%;
}

.youtube-music-img {
  width: 24px;
}

.youtube-music {
  width: 100%;
}

.library-img {
  width: 24px;
}

.library {
  width: 100%;
}
<div class="sidebar">
  <div class="home">
    <img class="home-img" src="https://dummyimage.com/20x20/000/fff" alt="">
    <p class="hp">Home</p>
  </div>
  <div class="explore">
    <img class="explore-img" src=".https://dummyimage.com/20x20/000/fff" alt="">
    <p class="ep">Explore</p>
  </div>
  <div class="subscriptions">
    <img class="subscriptions-img" src="https://dummyimage.com/20x20/000/fff" alt="">
    <p class="sp">Subsriptions</p>
  </div>
  <div class="originals">
    <img class="originals-img" src="https://dummyimage.com/20x20/000/fff" alt="">
    <p class="op">Originals</p>
  </div>
  <div class="youtube-music">
    <img class="youtube-music-img" src="https://dummyimage.com/20x20/000/fff" alt="">
    <p class="yp">Youtube Music</p>
  </div>
  <div class="library">
    <img class="library-img" src="https://dummyimage.com/20x20/000/fff" alt="">
    <p class="lp">Library</p>
  </div>

</div>



I am expecting the sidebar to look like below :


you can add a text-align: center to your menu container

I don't see a grid here but a flexbox

@MicheleDeFalco no, don't! He using flexbox, so he should use align-items: center

Not related to your problem. But classes exist so that you can reuse them. You really should have one class common class for all your children of sidebar. You can have, in addition, a distinct class for each item to style them individually. But for the common styling like width that is the same for all of them you should use a common class.

You must use display: flex with flex-direction: column and align-items: center in your div children of .sidebar like this:
.sidebar{
    background-color:rgb(175, 146, 146);
    width: 100px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: fixed;
    align-items: center;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    top:72px;
    padding-top: 15px;
}
p{
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 24px;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.home-img{
    width: 24px;
}
.home{
    width: 100%;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}
.explore-img{
    width: 24px;
}
.explore{
    width: 100%;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}
.subscriptions-img{
    width: 24px;
}
.subscriptions{
    width: 100%;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}
.originals-img{
    width: 24px;
}
.originals{
    width: 100%;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}
.youtube-music-img{
    width: 24px;
}
.youtube-music{
    width: 100%;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}
.library-img{
    width: 24px;
}
.library{
    width: 100%;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;

}


Thank you very much!
This can also be performed by using
text-align:centre
in the sidebar class

@DebdwaipayanBiswas text align has the disadvantage that it only works on inline elements. With display flex you have a much more versatile solution.
